# Error when trying to insert datagridview row collection to database using parameters

Tags: mysql, vb.net, exception, datagridview, parameters

I have a form with a datagridview that displays columns from a db table after being scanned using barcode scanner, the displayed datas then is supposed to be inserted to another table with additional information from the form like combobox text and label text but I kept getting an error. This is the code I use, this works on other forms but not with this one and I can't find out what's wrong.

```vb
Sub SewingReport()
    Try

        Dim sdate As String = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save this record to Sewing Report?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
            cn.Open()
            cm = Nothing
            cm = New MySqlCommand("insert into tblsewingreport (tsnumber, bundle#, itemcode, operation, color, size, quantity, price, amount, sdate, employee) values(@tsnumber, @bundle#, @itemcode, @operation, @color, @size, @quantity, @price, @amount, @sdate, @employee)", cn)

            For i = 0 To dgvRecord.Rows.Count - 1
                cm.Parameters.Clear()
                cn.Close()
                cn.Open()
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsnumber", lblInvoice.Text)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bundle#", dgvRecord.Rows(i).Cells("Column6").Value.ToString)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", dgvRecord.Rows(i).Cells("Column4").Value.ToString)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operation", dgvRecord.Rows(i).Cells("Column5").Value.ToString)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", dgvRecord.Rows(i).Cells("Column7").Value.ToString)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", dgvRecord.Rows(i).Cells("Column8").Value.ToString)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", CDec(dgvRecord.Rows(i).Cells("Column9").Value.ToString))
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", CDec(dgvRecord.Rows(i).Cells("Column10").Value.ToString))
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", CDec(dgvRecord.Rows(i).Cells("Column11").Value.ToString))
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", sdate)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee", ComboBox1.Text)
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery()

                cn.Close()
            Next
            MinusStockQty()

            MsgBox("Record has been successfully saved to Sewing Report.", vbInformation)
            lblInvoice.Text = GetInvoiceNo()
            txtSearch.Clear()
            txtSearch.Focus()


        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        cn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seRdc.jpg) message, the error throws on the ExecuteNonQuery line and all my datagrid column names are correct. This is the [datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAnLS.jpg) and this is my [database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wwan.jpg) im trying to insert to.

Comment: What you are doing is wrong for various reasons in varying degrees. First, don't open and close the connection on every iteration of the loop. Open the connection once, perform ALL interactions with the database over that connection, then close it.

Comment: Second, you shouldn't really use `AddWithValue` at all but certainly not in this scenario. Rather than `Clear` the `Parameters` collection and `Add` new parameters on every iteration, you ought to `Add` the parameters once and once only, then set the `Value` of each one on every iteration.

Comment: Finally, you shouldn't be using a loop at all. What you ought to do is create a `DataTable` with the appropriate schema and and bind that to your grid. You could add the columns to the `DataTable` yourself or you could call `FillSchema` on a data adapter. When you're ready to save, you then call `Update` on a data adapter to save the whole `DataTable` in one go. You can use the same data adapter to call `FillSchema` and `Update` and, if you want, you can use a command builder to generate the `InsertCommand` and all the parameters too.

Comment: Actually, I see another issue with your code. Why are you taking a `Date` and converting it to a `String` and then saving that to the database? Please tell me that you're not storing dates as text. You should be storing dates as dates, which means saving a `Date` to the database. That would mean, at the very least, using this: `cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", Date.Today)`.

Comment: Thank you for all the observations jm! I'm still trying to learn stuff and this helps a lot. I deleted the 2 other close and open connection in the code now. I was clearing parameters and using addwithvalue because i was getting an error saying "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" that throws from the parameters line.

Comment: Also, I use data and converts it to string because thats the only easy way I know to insert dates (may column datatype is DATE not TEXT). Thank you for the information I will be using `cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", Date.Today)` from now on. Also edited the title thanks for the help.

Comment: Here are a couple of tutorial/example posts of mine that may help, on [ADO.NET](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) in general and [parameters](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific issue in this case is almost certainly the `bundle#` column name. Any identifiers that contain spaces or other special characters need to be escaped. The MySQL standard for that is to use graves while the Microsoft standard is to use brackets. I believe that the MySQL ADO.NET provider (Connector/Net) supports both:

```vb
cm = New MySqlCommand("insert into tblsewingreport (tsnumber, `bundle#`, itemcode, ...
```

or:

```vb
cm = New MySqlCommand("insert into tblsewingreport (tsnumber, [bundle#], itemcode, ...
```

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney!! Finally found out the problem. I just changed my database column name to just "bundle" now it all works.  I never realized it would be a problem.

Comment: Avoiding problematic names in the first place is definitely the best way to go.